# using returned value of tuple

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a function

```
public Tuple<bool, string> check()
{

.
.
return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, null);
}
```

Now I want to call this check() function in my main code. Whats the right way to do? I was thinking to do the following. but it does not work.

```
Tuple<bool, string> chk = new Tuple<bool, string>(check());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a new object as part of your call to the function. Just use this:

```
Tuple<bool, string> chk = check();
```

Answer (score 2):

Methods are called with the identifier of who owns the method. You return type is a `Tuple`, but it is not the `Tuple` who owns the `Check` method.

The object who owns the method in your case is certainly `this` in that context.

So call it this way instead :

```
var chk = this.check();
```